# Concurrent users and multiple observers

Tags: firebase

I know there is already [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307341/how-exactly-are-concurrent-users-determined-for-a-firebase-app) on how the number of concurrent users is calculated in Firebase, but it doesn't answer my question, which is: if a single user has multiple observers to multiple locations in a single Firebase application, does it count as one or several concurrent users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple observers to multiple location from the same Firebase *connection* is counted as one concurrent only. Every web page shares a single connection to a given Firebase, but not across iframes or tabs. Every node.js, iOS or Android process will share one connection per Firebase as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any source on this? Their doc didn't seem very clear to me on that point, but maybe I missed something

Comment: I work at Firebase :)

Feel free to email support@firebase.com if you have any other billing related concerns.