# Polymer 1.0 firebase-element and number of connections

Tags: firebase, firebase-polymer

I'm building an app using firebase in Polymer.  It is tempting to create a new firebase-collection for each ajax call I might have made in the past.  Since firebase.com bills based on the maximum number of simultaneous connections (sessions?), I'm worried that the firebase-element components each count as one connection.  Thus, if there are ten firebase-elements in a page it will be counted as 10 connections instead of one.

Do I need to design the page to minimize the number of firebase-elements?  How are connections counted when using firebase-elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase opens a web socket when a page makes a first connection to its servers. All subsequent data reads/writes for that page happen over the same web socket.

Also see:

- [Concurrent users and multiple observers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597722/concurrent-users-and-multiple-observers)
- [How exactly are concurrent users determined for a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307341/how-exactly-are-concurrent-users-determined-for-a-firebase-app)