# Firebase simultaneous connection count for one client with multiple queries

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android app, I have an activity, a fragment and a dialog at the same time, each having their own `addValueEventListener()` for different queries. What is the simultaneous connection count at this time? Is it one because all requests coming from one client or is it three because each different request counts as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single client maintains a single connection to the Firebase Database servers. All read and write operation re-use this same connection.

Also see:

- [How the Connection is calculated in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466522/how-the-connection-is-calculated-in-firebase) (for JavaScript, but all Firebase SDK work the same in this respect)
- [Concurrent users and multiple observers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597722/concurrent-users-and-multiple-observers) (for iOS, but all Firebase SDK work the same in this respect :-)
- [How exactly are concurrent users determined for a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307341/how-exactly-are-concurrent-users-determined-for-a-firebase-app/14307743#14307743)
- [Clarify the Firebase connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070095/clarify-the-firebase-connections)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I checked before I asked but I have missed the second link.